# Printing 2 dimensional char array in c++

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, char

I dont understand why I can't print out this character array using the void function print_board which takes in the character array as parameter, initilize it and print it. Gives me 
[Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char (*)[8]' [-fpermissive]
[Error] initializing argument 1 of 'void print_board(char (*)[8])' [-fpermissive]

what am i missing or doing wrong here?

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 void print_board(char [8][8]);


 int main() {
 char board[8][8];
 print_board(board[8][8]);

return 0;
}


void print_board(char board[8][8])
{

for(int i = 0;i<8;i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<8; j++)
    {

    board[i][j] = '.';
    cout<<board[i][j];
    }



   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main function you are not passing the array properly plus function header should be like this

```
print_board(board); // This should be in main

void print_board(board[][8])
{
    // Do something
}
```

For more detail visit [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function)

Comment: its:  print_board(board[8][8])

Comment: Do add `cout<<"\n";` when inner `for(;;)` loop ends to print it like board, if you want

Answer (score 0):

You're passing board[8][8] which is of type char.

print_board expects an array of char[8] given your definition of the function.

Change the invocation to `print_board(board);`

Comment: its array supposed to store characters.